# new line appending on encrypting string in java

Tags: java, encryption

In Main :

```
String password = "spK47@wF";
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes("UTF8"));
        byte[] digestedPwdBytes = md.digest();
        Base64 encoder = new Base64();
        System.out.print(new String(encoder.encode(digestedPwdBytes)) +":");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Desired Output: `ymm/nnotV+vzSKnXtjubqA==:`

Output i am getting :

```
ymm/nnotV+vzSKnXtjubqA==
:
```

How I can remove that extra new line. Why is this new line getting appended to the encrypted string?

Comment: If you were using the [`Base64.Encoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#withoutPadding--) class, you could call `withoutPadding()`. As you are apparently using some other `Base64` class, hard to say without you saying which class that is.

Comment: Are you using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`?

Comment: Which `Base64` class are you using? It's not `java.util.Base64` from JDK 8.

Comment: Also, beware that `new String(byte[])` will use the default character encoding on your system, which may not be what you want. Use the `String` constructor where you can specify the encoding explicitly.

Comment: my java version is `1.6.0_45` and i am using `org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64` @rparree @Jesper

Comment: I am not getting the extra line when using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` (not `net` but `codec`)

Comment: MD5 is not encryption, it is a one-way hash function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With Apache Commons *Net*

Set the `line-length` to `0`:

```
Base64 encoder = new Base64(0);
System.out.print(new String(encoder.encode(digestedPwdBytes)) +":");
```

*output:*

```
ymm/nnotV+vzSKnXtjubqA==:
```

From the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/Base64.html)

> Line length: Default 76. Line length that aren't multiples of 4 will still essentially end up being multiples of 4 in the encoded data.

and

> If lineLength <= 0, then the output will not be divided into lines (chunks). Ignored when decoding.

### Apache Commons *Codec*

Or use  **Apache Commons Codec**: `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`

```
Base64 encoder = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64();
System.out.print(new String(encoder.encode(digestedPwdBytes)) +":");
```

Comment: problem solved using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`

Comment: what is the problem with `org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64`. why does it append new line with encrypted string? @rparree

Comment: `org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64` implements [RFC 2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) that describes mime (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) .. RFC 2045 includes requirements like:"The encoded output stream must be represented in lines of no more
 than 76 characters each" etc ..